# How do I select 50 to 100 rows from Azure Table using the StorageClient?

Tags: linq, ado.net, azure, azure-table-storage

I need to select several rows within a single partition of Azure Tables for later update.  Since they all have the same PartitionKey, how do I structure my query to select multiple RowKeys?

I'm interested in what the raw (on the wire) query should look like, and if possible the Linq query as well.

I attempted this on my own and started with this query:

```
 var results = from c in _ServiceContext.ForumThreadTable
                          where(
                          (
                          (c.RowKey == rk)    ||
                          (c.RowKey == "n1q") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "gm1w") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "fm1e") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "zbm1r") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "km1te1") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "jm1ye1") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "hm1u") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "gm1i") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "fm1te1") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "d4m1ye1") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "bm1u") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "bm1i") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "bm1o") ||
                          (c.RowKey == "bp1p") 
                          ) &&

                          c.PartitionKey == pk )
                          select c;
```

My query looked like this (from fiddler)

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/ForumThreadTable()?$filter=(((((((((((((((RowKey%20eq%20'0634205427898279774')%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'n1q'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'gm1w'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'fm1e'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'zbm1r'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'km1te1'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'jm1ye1'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'hm1u'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'gm1i'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'fm1te1'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'd4m1ye1'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'bm1u'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'bm1i'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'bm1o'))%20or%20(RowKey%20eq%20'bp1p'))%20and%20(PartitionKey%20eq%20'GUIDeec4550c-a3fd-472b-9b7d-c79fae664415') HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0;NetFx
x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
x-ms-date: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 02:49:48 GMT
Authorization: SharedKeyLite devstoreaccount1:MINFtQhWqbnYhn1spDGTGvPmNmW24YNzOeqBBtOletU=
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/xml
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:10002
```

and here is my error:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
 <error xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\">
 <code>InvalidInput</code>
 <message xml:lang=\"en-US\">One of the request inputs is not valid.</message>
 </error>"
```

I think it may have to do more with the quantity of RowKey conditions I have, rather than the syntax... but I'm open to try anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's something similar to what we've been doing in [Lokad.Cloud](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/). As I recall you can select up to 100 rows in this manner without problems.  You can check the [source code for the details](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/source/browse/trunk/Source/Lokad.Cloud.Framework/Storage/Azure/TableStorageProvider.cs) and reuse either the entire open source project or just the parts you like.

Here's how the syntax generation looks like:

```
public IEnumerable<CloudEntity<T>> Get<T>(string tableName, string partitionKey, IEnumerable<string> rowKeys)
{
  Enforce.That(() => tableName);
  Enforce.That(() => partitionKey);
  Enforce.That(!partitionKey.Contains("'"), "Incorrect char in partitionKey.");

  var context = _tableStorage.GetDataServiceContext();

  foreach (var slice in rowKeys.Slice(MaxEntityTransactionCount))
  {
    // work-around the limitation of ADO.NET that does not provide a native way
    // of query a set of specified entities directly.
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(string.Format("(PartitionKey eq '{0}') and (", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(partitionKey)));
    for (int i = 0; i < slice.Length; i++)
    {
      // in order to avoid SQL-injection-like problems 
      Enforce.That(!slice[i].Contains("'"), "Incorrect char in rowKey.");

      builder.Append(string.Format("(RowKey eq '{0}')", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(slice[i])));
      if (i < slice.Length - 1)
      {
        builder.Append(" or ");
      }
    }
    builder.Append(")");

    foreach(var entity in GetInternal<T>(context, tableName, builder.ToString()))
    {
      yield return entity;
    }
  }
}
```

However, please keep in mind, that this operation will not be optimized by the table storage, resulting in suboptimal performance (table storage is not using indexes for this operation). This is a bug that was reported to Microsoft and is expected to be fixed some time soon.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any update on progress with this bug fix. Is Azure Table storage now performing this type of query (multiple rowkey with OR operation on single partition) using indexes?